# Change the content of one page when button clicked in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on designing a website, which I have two pages the first page contains a button when  it's clicked the hidden class belongs to some element from the second page must be removed. I searched a lot but nothing works for me, Hope you can help me.
The first page contains something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary add" >Click me!</button>
```

The second page contains something like this:

```
<div class="hidden" id="someDivId">Some content!</div>
```

jQuery code in the first page:

```
$('.add').click(function (){

  //Access the second page 
  //Remove hidden class from #someDivId   

});
```

Comment: Firstly your question is far too broad. Without knowing the context of your code we can't help you. Secondly, how are you expecting to affect the second page when it's not loaded?

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan. However may be you could investigate Window.postMessage()? See here for an example: https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage for storing data through the pages. After user opens website page with hidden element you just call javascript which checks the localStorage.

```
$(".add").click(function() {
  //sets hidden on false
  localStorage.setItem("hidden", false);
})


//on another website page load check localstorage value
  let isHidden = localStorage.getItem("hidden") ? localStorage.getItem("hidden") : false;

  if(isHidden) {
    $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
  }
```

Comment: Every one of them ( the div and the button ) is in a different page!

Comment: Different page means different page on same website or completely different site?

Comment: Different pages on same website.